# How to get more subfigures than 26?

Tags: subfloats, loops

Code where having 6 subfigure environment causes the error but not less because I run out of labels of subfigures: a), b), ..., n), but I need more

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\foreach \ii in {1,...,5}{
\centering% not \center!
\begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.11, page=\ii]{{Rplots.bland.male.5}.pdf}
  \caption{\#\ii, ite. 1.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.11, page=\ii]{{Rplots.blandmale.6}.pdf}
  \caption{\#\ii, ite. 2.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.11, page=\ii]{{Rplots.bland.male.7}.pdf}
  \caption{\#\ii, ite. 3.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.11, page=\ii]{{Rplots.bland.8}.pdf}
  \caption{\#\ii, ite. 4.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.11, page=\ii]{{Rplots.bland.9}.pdf}
  \caption{\#\ii, ite. 5.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.11, page=\ii]{{Rplots.bland.10}.pdf}
  \caption{\#\ii, ite. 6.}
\end{subfigure}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Error

```
! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1492 }

?
```

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Does the error message also state *which counter* is too large?

Comment: Do you have 5 pages in all the pdfs? Also, you need `\end{figure}` but I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: surely you could have provided a proper example?

Comment: Your subfigs are numbered a, b, c, ... After 26 pictures you run out of letters. That's what the error message tells you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `alphalph` provides some ways to continue numbering with letters, if the number of letters is exhausted, e.g.:

```
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\img}{%
  \includegraphics[
    width=\linewidth,
    height=20pt,
    keepaspectratio=false,
  ]{example-image-a}%
}

\begin{figure}
\foreach \ii in {1,...,5}{%
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
    \centering
    \img
    \caption{\#\ii, ite. 1.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
    \centering
    \img
    \caption{\#\ii, ite. 2.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
    \centering
    \img
    \caption{\#\ii, ite. 3.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
    \centering
    \img
    \caption{\#\ii, ite. 4.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
    \centering
    \img
    \caption{\#\ii, ite. 5.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.19\textwidth}
    \centering
    \img
    \caption{\#\ii, ite. 6.}
  \end{subfigure}
}%
\lastlinefit=1000 % same inter-image spaces in last line as in previous lines
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

That error is given if you use `\alph` or `\Alph` and have a value more than 26.

If you need values bigger than that you need a different display function.

Comment: How can you have more labels in subfigure? - The 26 is too few for me. Now it is like a), b), .., n) but I really need more those subfigures.

Comment: @masi there are packages such as alpalph that give longer alphabetic sequences or you can use roman numerals or some other scheme

Comment: why the downvote? This does pinpoint the problem doesn't it?